# WSO2 ESB: HTTP-NIO doesn't deliver WSDL for tenant's service

Tags: soap, wsdl, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB version 4.8.1 with tenant created and this tenant has defined proxy service  with published WSDL.

If I switch from HTTP PassThrough transport to HTTP-NIO transport (by copying `axis2_nhttp.xml` to file `axis2.xml`) I can't get WSDL for tenant's service. Nothing else in configuration is changed.

Getting WSDL for "super-tenant" works fine with both transports, but accessing tenant's proxy service `http://esb.localhost:8280/services/t/tenant.net/StockInfo?wsdl` in browser results in "No Data Received".

In log of ESB I get:

```
INFO - LogMediator To: local://axis2services/StockInfo?wsdl, MessageID: urn:uuid:9c46e320-6147-4892-88ac-c5a73b53d1ee, Direction: request
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in WSO2 ESB?

Comment: We ran into the same issue, so I have created a [WSO2 JIRA ticket](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3391) for this.